# How can I determine whether a file in a PostgreSQL data directory is used in the database?

Tags: postgresql

I have a situation in which summing the size of the tables in a tablespace (using pg_class among others) reveals that there is 550G of datafiles in a particular tablespace in a particular database.

However, there is 670G of files in that directory on the server.

FWIW, I don't know how that can be.  No files have been written to that directory via any mechanism other than Postgres.  My best guess is perhaps the database crashed while an autovacuum was going on, leaving orphan files laying around...does that sound plausible?)

SO, I've worked out a way, by reading the contents of a ls command into the database, strip off the numeric extensions for tables > 1G in size, and compare them with the contents of pg_class, and have, in fact, found about 120G of files not reflected in pg_class.

My question is, is it safe for me to delete these files, or could they be in active use by the database but not reflected in pg_class?

Answer (score 1):

**Do not manually delete files in the PostgreSQL data directory.**

This is *not* safe and *will* corrupt your database.

**The safe way** to purge any files that don't belong to the database is to perform a `pg_dumpall`, stop the server, remove the data directory and the contents of all tablespace directories, breate a new cluster with `inindb` and restore the dump.

If you want to investigate the issue, you could try to create a new tablespace and move everything from the old to the new tablespace. I will describe that in the rest of my answer.

Move all the tables and indexes *in all databases* to the new tablespace:

```
ALTER TABLE ALL IN TABLESPACE oldtblsp SET TABLESPACE newtblsp;
ALTER INDEX ALL IN TABLESPACE oldtblsp SET TABLESPACE newtblsp;
```

If `oldtblsp` is the default tablespace of a database:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET TABLESPACE newtblsp;
```

Then run a checkpoint:

```
CHECKPOINT;
```

Make sure you forgot no database:

```
SELECT datname
FROM pg_database d
   JOIN pg_tablespace s
      ON d.dattablespace = s.oid
WHERE s.spcname = 'oldtblsp';
```

Make sure that there are no objects in the old tablespace by running this query *in all databases*:

```
SELECT t.relname, t.relnamespace::regnamespace, t.relkind
FROM pg_class t
   JOIN pg_tablespace s
      ON t.reltablespace = s.oid
WHERE s.spcname = 'oldtblsp';
```

This should return no results.

Now the old tablespace should be empty and you can

```
DROP TABLESPACE oldtblsp;
```

If you *really* get an error

```
ERROR:  tablespace "tblsp" is not empty
```

there might be some files left behind.

Delete them at your own risk...